# Изменить цвет элемента для отрывания меню в зависимости от страницы в модуле drawer для react-component

Tags: css, reactjs, menu

Есть модуль для показа и скрывания меню https://github.com/react-component/drawer. При нажатии на элемент меню появляется, при повторном прячется. Вот реализованный пример https://codesandbox.io/s/ykq7rlzmz9. Есть необходимость менять цвет этого элемента с темного на светлый на главной странице, поскольку она такая же темная и элемента не видно. В примере одна страница. Исходя из описания можно сделать префикс для css и менять его в зависимости от страницы или другого условия для всего модуля:

```
`<Drawer prefixCls={myCondition ? myClass : myOtherClass}>`
```

или задавать вообще сам элемент

```
`handler={isMain ? (<div className="mydrawer-handle"><i className="mydrawer-handle-icon" /></div>) : (<div className="drawer-handle"><i className="drawer-handle-icon" /></div>)} .`
```

Но когда я меняю первое или второе свойство делая их отличными от того, что задано по умолчанию, этот элемент перестает показываться. Даже если без условий только задать единственное значение `prefixCls='mydrawer'` вместо 'drawer' или `handler=(<div className="mydrawer-handle"><i className="mydrawer-handle-icon" /></div>)`, даже при том, что указанные css коды находятся в одном файле и идентичны исходным, кроме наименования этот элемент перестает отображаться. Разработчик не отвечает на данные вопросы. Прошу помощи изменить цвет элемента в зависимости от переменной (указателя на определенную страницу сайта) с примером. 
После того как задал вопрос, продолжил эксперименты и обнаружил, что элемент уходит за край страницы. Но ведь css одинаковый в обоих случаях.

Comment: не понятно о цвете какого элемента идёт речь. бургера?

Comment: в общем ответ тут https://github.com/react-component/drawer/blob/master/assets/index.less#L57

Comment: цвет полосок для открывания меню как и потом крестика в которых они превращаются в less я могу задать , но навсегда. а нужно в зависимости от текущей страницы или другого параметра. вопрос в том не как изнутри все поменять, я это в css файле сделал, а о том как оперативно снаружи управлять параметрами отображения.

Comment: я и не предлагал менять лесс файл. Но ведь там указаны имена классов для полосок. вот и получается что то вроде `body.dark .drawer-icon { background-color: white; }` (css)

Comment: если вы меняете префикс ничего не работает потому что этот префикс захардкожен  в цсс файл пакета

Comment: понимаю, но не могу это обойти. 2 дня рассматриваю код безрезультатно. цель - на главной этот бургер показывать белыми линиями, а на остальных черными. делать свой элемент и работать через state не хочется, ибо теряется смысл модуля. получается, что если делать `prefixCls='mydrawer'` то вообще перестает меняться css класс на `drawer-handle drawer-open` при открытии меню. полоски не становятся крестиком. как бы баг. в issue я постарался написать, но никакой реакции. Написал сюда надеясь, что кто-нибудь поможет сделать чтобы менялся класс этого хандлера в зависимости от переданного параметра.

Comment: так я же написал сверху решение: добавьте этот css: `body.dark .drawer-icon { background-color: white; }`, на главной задайте `class="dark"` у <body> и готово

Comment: возможно стоит добавить "!important". как оно может не воспринимать.. в  хром инпекторе можно посмотреть точно как называется класс, которые отвечает за цвет (хотя кажется что именно drawer-icon), ну или выложите код может

Comment: проблема то не про реакт, а про css и хтмл по сути

Answer (score 0):

Нашел все же как изменить код компонента чтобы влиял параметр и на "бургер". Взял за основу дефолтный код этого элемента и добавил префикс.